# Правильные хлебные крошки с микроразметкой?

Tags: html5, seo, валидация, breadcrumbs

Столкнулся с непониманием семантики структуры создания breadcrumbs с микроразметкой. Есть вот такая структура.

```html
<ul class='bl_breadcrumbs' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList'>
  <li itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/ListItem'>
    <a itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemprop='item' href='/'><span itemprop='name'>Главная</span></a>
    <meta itemprop='position' content='1'>
  </li>
  <li class='uk-active' itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/ListItem'>
    <a itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemprop='item' href='/NetGame-Entertainment' title='NetGame Entertainment'><span itemprop='name'>NetGame Entertainment</span></a>
    <meta itemprop='position' content='2'>
  </li>
  <li class='uk-active' itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/ListItem'>
    <a itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemprop='item' href='/Golden-skulls' title=''><span itemprop='name'>Golden skulls</span></a>
    <meta itemprop='position' content='3'>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Согласно [тестам от Гугла](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) BreadcrumbList составлен верно. Но вот если начинать читать рекомендации, что дескать "нежелательно" последний элемент хлебных крошек заворачивать в тег ссылку (вся schema org ломается), опять же, если проверять данный кусок html через [W3C валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), то он тоже мне говорит, что я не прав. 
[image: некорректные хлебные крошки]
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ и избавиться от ошибок в валидаторе W3C и не поломать микроразметку пройдя тесты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3C валидатор ругался на отсутствующие атрибуты **itemscope**.

Я их добавил так, чтобы валидация успешно проходила, в теги `<ul>` и `<a>`.

Также для корректной валидации разметки schema.org необходимо было добавить **id** в тег `<a>`.

В продакшене используется id страницы/записи на которую ведет ссылка, под id подразумевается UUID, id, url, slug, лучше всего использовать относительный путь (также рекомендую использовать относительный путь и в `href`)

```html
<ul class='bl_breadcrumbs' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList'>
  <li itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/ListItem'>
    <a itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemscope itemprop='item' id='/'  href='/'>
        <span itemprop='name'>Главная</span>
    </a>
    <meta itemprop='position' content='1'>
  </li>
  <li class='uk-active' itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/ListItem'>
    <a itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemscope itemprop='item' id='NetGame-Entertainment' href='/NetGame-Entertainment' title='NetGame Entertainment'>
        <span itemprop='name'>NetGame Entertainment</span>
    </a>
    <meta itemprop='position' content='2'>
  </li>
  <li class='uk-active' itemprop='itemListElement' itemscope itemtype='https://schema.org/ListItem'>
    <!-- Здесь заменяем <a> на <span>, чтобы убрать ссылку на себя -->
    <span itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemscope itemprop='item' id='Golden-skulls' title=''>
        <span itemprop='name'>Golden skulls</span>
    </span>
    <meta itemprop='position' content='3'>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А что значит, (в продакшене используется id страницы/записи на которую ведет ссылка) ? Где этот id должен быть указан на той странице (допустим в моем случае есть некая страница рубрики /NetGame-Entertainment), к какому тегу прописан, откуда такая информация? И ещё вопрос, есть ли возможность не использовать ссылку для последнего элемента  разметки schema.org ? (что бы страница не ссылалась сама на себя?)

Comment: @BlackStar1991, обновил ответ, в нем ответил на вопрос по id и на последней крошке убрал ссылку, правильно подметили все.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно валидатор W3 ругается на тот факт, что ваша разметка на использует элемент микродата такой как itemscope, например:

```
<a itemtype='https://schema.org/Thing' itemprop='item' href='/'>
```

Проверьте следующую информацию из **[документации Схемы](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)**:

> Добавляя itemscope, вы указываете, что HTML, содержащийся в
>   блоке исходного кода, относится к определенному элементу.

Вы указали этот элемент при внедрении типов BreadcrumbList и ListItem, но игнорируете этот элемент для типа Thing.

Comment: Куда этот элемент вводить, что бы пройти гугл тест? И есть ли возможность заменить последнюю ссылку в хлебных крошках на другой тег, предположим span, что б пройти тесты без ошибок ?